# How do I root Micromax Canvas 2 A110?

Tags: rooting, micromax-a110

I want to root [Micromax Canvas 2 A110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromax_Canvas_2_A110) having [Android ICS 4.0.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.0.x_Ice_Cream_Sandwich). How do I root it?

Comment: And added to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following instructions are from [androidforums.com](http://androidforums.com/canvas-2-a110-all-things-root/644239-how-root-micromax-a110-micromax-canvas-a110-exclusive-guide.html) site.

The summary of the rooting procedure (*just copied and pasted* - credit goes to **sagarwep** the poster of the procedure) is as below:

1. Enable USB debugging on your device. To do that, go to Settings > Development > USB debugging.
2. Connect your device to any PC/laptop. The drivers will be installed automatically.
3. Download [Bin4ry for Root A110 By sagarwep.7z](http://www.mediafire.com/?73yelcak6rcfcca) and unzip.
4. Run `RunMe.bat` from the extracted location.
5. [image: List item]
6. A command prompt with weird green letters will pop-up on your screen.
   Follow the onscreen instructions carefully. To start off, you willl need to type in a "1" and press enter. [Note: If you ever want to Unroot your Micromax A110, follow the above steps till you reach this one and then, instead of typing "1", type "x" and hit enter. Follow the instructions that appear on the command prompt after that.]
7. Your device will reboot during the process after which Bin4ry will copy some files to your device.
8. With [RootChecker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) you can verify whether the phone is rooted or not.

Comment: Please let us know about your success in using this procedure.

Comment: Actually I **searched** on this site only. Couldn't find any post regarding this. That's why I asked. :)

Comment: @Narayanan I have the same phone but my Android version is 4.2.1 Can I use the same method or should I post a new specific question